# Word Backstage Customisation - Office 2021 changes

Tags: .net, ms-word, office365, office-addins, ribbonx

With Office 2021 Microsoft have added the control on the Info tab shown in screenshot below of and we need to disable or hide it if the document is part of the clinical application (we only intervene on documents that are part of the application - we have a Word Add-In that controls that).

I cannot find any dociumentation to tell me the idMso of this new control of group of controls and none of the Microsoft documentation appears to have been updated beyond Office 2019. I'm suspicious that this control may not follow the rules!

Can you help find the idMso(s) please.

It's the 5 button group (Upload, Share etc) not the document name and location that I am referring to.

Image shows the 5 buttons I'm referring to.

[image: Top of TabInfo showing 5 new buttons]

The are more changes but this is the most critical.

Extensive searching has stopped at documentation for Office 2019 but a complete blank on Office 2021.

Comment: This is also present in Word 365. The line in blue is the filename. The location is under that. What is it that you wish to eliminate?

Comment: The 5 butttons under the part you mention - they appear only for saved documents - my screenshot shows them: Upload, Share, Copy Path, Copy Local Path, Open File Location (the latter ones are not the standard idMso we can control)

Comment: Your document *is* a saved document, although in the Temp folder with a weird name. Those buttons all appear in my Word 365 with downloaded and temporary documents as well as ones that I have deliberately saved. This may be a bug (unintended feature).

Comment: You are correct - the documents are controlled by our application and stored on the server after creation/editing/printing (the Guid file name and temporary storage location are visbile but I'n not concerned about those - we can hide them as they have idMso's). The buttons are a risk but there is no sign of the idMso's we need to disable them.

Comment: Someone on the Word Answers forum may know. Post as a discussion rather than as a question to avoid getting responses from IAs who are paid to answer quickly but often have no expertise. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  If you do post there as well, please observe standard cross-posting etiquette. https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: "Extensive searching has stopped at documentation for Office 2019 but a complete blank on Office 2021." - I couldn't find documentation for anything later than Office 2016! Where did you find the 2019 control IDs?

Comment: That was from GitHub:

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers/tree/84f8506c56218410b0c474b4f07bb0b03687369a

Comment: But it does not have what we need as there is a lot of stuff that, best guess, diverges from the rules and does not behave like stuff with Control Identifiers. I have not researched further in the last year but if anything turns up I'd be glad to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of built-in ribbon control IDs at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers. If you don't see such IDs listed in the documents you may try to locate them on the `Options` dialog, see `Customize Ribbon` tab, for example:

[image: ribbon controls IDs]

When you hover over a particular entry the `msoId` value is shown as a popup.

Comment: I'm afraid the link is only up to Office 2019 and not updated for 5 years and the option to find them from the Customize Ribbon gives no clues - I'm beginning to think MS have "cheated" to add these new options to 2021. I've been searching every lead I can find on the Internet and raised it with MS directly as a Partner but nothing so far.

Comment: The list of control IDs may not contain all the controls. That's why the `Customize Ribbon` section is suggested. There is no other way to get control IDs.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your comments but I'm afraid I have been through the list in Customize Ribbon without any success. I'm 99% sure the control(s) in question don't have idMsos associated with them. Our only option at the moment is to hide TabInfo but I'm concerned that there are more bits we can no longer control - including the cloud sharing option in the Title bar. Unless anyone knows a way to contact the MS Office dev team directly - not like the old days when Partners could get direct help.

Comment: PS Apologies if I'm posting my comments the wrong way - I don't really understand the Help between Add Comment and Answer Your Question - I used Add Comment because I don't know the Answer.

Comment: Add comment is the method here of holding a conversation. The Answer pane is reserved for things that (should) solve the problem. --- I am guessing, but do not know, that these are in a Group on the Info Tab. Have you tried looking at the native XML? (Not fun, I know!)

Comment: Happy to read Xml - but which Xml. I've been through the Schema but like everything else MS have not published any changes for Office 2021. (PS I cross-posted as per your recommendation.)